# Add property value to dictionary of columns names in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a custom method for returning an SQLAlchemy object as a dictionary in Flask:

```
class Script(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "script"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(144), index=True)
audio_filename = db.Column(db.String(144))


@property
def audio_file_path(self):
    return os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'voices/', self.audio_filename)

def as_dict(self):
    return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

This works fine for the column fields but I also want to include the return values of model properties.

My question is, what is the most pythonic way of returning the `@property` value of `audio_file_path` in the dictionary too.

I know this works:

```
def as_dict(self):
    d = {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
    d['audio_file_path'] = self.audio_file_path
    return d
```

But it's not very pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiple attributes with the `property` decorator, you can use the `vars` to iterate through the class and check if the item is a `property`.

```
def as_dict(self):

    props = {k: getattr(self, k) for (k, v) in vars(self.__class__).items() 
             if type(v) is property}

    columns = {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
    columns.update(**props)

    return columns
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.